# Torch-rnn sample.lua binary file exporting

Tags: java, torch

I've been experimenting with Torch for a while now, and I wrote my own audio file format.

In that I want to have my data stored in bytes, so I would use all 256 possible values in the file.
I put my file in preprocess.py with 'bytes' encoding, it threw no exceptions. The training goes well, too, but when I'm generating sample data, it is not really bytecode. Some of the characters are written out and some byte values are just in brackets.

`[158][170][171][147][164][199][201][179][170][185][184][163][134][130][151][164][150][130]xnjlbUQcq]Vg|ysx{[130]|svzv[144][168][152][137]m[136][150][134][135][135][177][167][130][128][150][167][159][146][132][131][135]Wm{[155]}mqm[143]x[138]r[140][131][135]yv[135]}enj[138][145][141][140][150][128]mrj[132]vv[133][150][152][155][136][140][159][149][152][131]{[139]wmTPQ\bqveMYk[128]uvt[141][147][139][132][132][143][143][132][148][178][187][174][166][164][150]zt[137]xeo~xjt|x~zxx[130]tgp}[147][141][137][139]`

How could I change sample.lua's output? I did make a change but I do not know Lua. This is what I wrote:

`local sample = model:sample(opt)
 local out = io.open(opt.output, "wb")
 out:write(sample)
 out:close()`

instead of

`local sample = model:sample(opt)
 print(sample)`

That resulted the same output. What could I do to get it working?